# parse names to a listview with XMLPullParser

Tags: android, parsing, listview, android-xmlpullparser

I went to many sites to learn how to use XmlPullParser but it still confuse in my head..

I have this xml :

```
<campagne>
    <sms>
       <texte>Vente a Drouot</texte>
           <list>
               <id> 1 </id>
                    <nom> TOTO </nom>
               <id> 2 </id>
                    <nom> TATA </nom>
              <id> 3 </id>
                    <nom> Mr.Gerard </nom>
           </list>
   </sms>
</campagne>
```

So I have a mainActivity with a button "get the xml".
When I click to the button it goes to a second activity with a LISTVIEW and an EDITTEXT.
In my editText i managed to get the text in the node "texte" (Vente a drouot), but now I want to get all the names in nodes "nom" to insert them to the listview...

For now I have this :

```
public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        String text = null;
        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType();
            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = myParser.getName();
                switch (event) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = myParser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (name.equals("texte")) {
                        message = text;
                    } else {
                    }
                    break;
                }
                event = myParser.next();

            }
            parsingComplete = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Anyone can give me a little help please ? 
thank you

Comment: So what is the problem? You have to fetch all data including the tag of `nom` and store that data in arraylist or you can use getter setter method for that.

Comment: problem is I don't really know how to fetch all data including the tag of "nom".. a loop to get all the data ?? sorry i'm starting at android java :/

Comment: Yes you have to. Further more you can go with this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_xml_parsers.htm , http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: thank you for your reply but I already checked this site.. I just dont know how to put all the data inside the nodes "nom" to a listview I created in a layout.xml

Comment: And yes you can fetch nom tag as a string and add it to arraylist and pass that list to listview adpater